# SQL Server 2016: Group by while updating the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, window-functions

I have a scenario wherein I need to determine the Margin Type for each Customer/Business combination against a product - meaning the Product with the highest Margin for a Customer /Business combination should be identified as 'High' Margin Type. All the other Product with the same combination should be identified as Low. So, I need a SQL to update the column MARGIN_TYPE accordingly.

I tried doing something like this, but do not understand how to group it by customer/business combination. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
UPDATE ORDER_TABLE
SET MARGIN_TYPE = 'High'
where MARGIN = (SELECT MARGIN FROM (SELECT MAX(MARGIN) FROM ORDER_TABLE) AS 
MARGIN)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* you just want an updatable CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Customer,
           Margin,
           MarginType,
           MAX(Margin) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) AS MaxMargin
    FROM dbo.YOurTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET MarginType = CASE Margin WHEN MaxMargin THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I dont think this would also group by business. Would it?

Comment: Then add `Business` to the `PARTITION BY`, @Newbie . I was basing this on the (very) small sample set we had, where both `Customer` and `Business` change at the same time.

Comment: thanks @Larnu. there seem to be some issue with the CASE statement and i do not understand what Margin WHEN MaxMargin mean.

Comment: @Newbie the `CASE` **expression** (`Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in T-SQL) is perfectly valid... And it does "what is says on the tin". When Margin has the value MaxMargin return `High` else `Low`. `CASE` expressions are pretty basic parts of the language. If you supply consumable sample data (not an image) I'll be happy to test the above/provide a fiddle. You shouldn't, however, expect users to transcribe your data (and that's probably why you have a downvote).

Comment: Try now, @Newbie . The error would have *really* help, along with that sample data... The error had nothing to do with the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2):

With an updatebale CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER, BUSINESS ORDER BY MARGIN DESC) rn
  FROM ORDER_TABLE
)
UPDATE cte
SET MARGIN_TYPE = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
merge into ORDER_TABLE  OT
using (select customer, business, product, margin, case when rnk = 1 then 'High' else 
'Low' end as MARGIN_TYPE
select customer, business, product, margin, row_number() over (partition by customer, 
business, product, margin order by margin desc) as rnk
from ORDER_TABLE
group by) QRY
on (OT.customer = QRY.customer and OT.business = QRY.business and OT.margin = 
QRY.margin)
when matched then
update
set 
OT.MARGIN_TYPE = QRY.MARGIN_TYPE;
```

Comment: . . `merge` is way overkill for what the OP wants to do.  I would suggest that you look at Larnu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ORD
SET MARGIN_TYPE = case ORD.margin = m.margin then 'high' else 'low' end
from ORDER_TABLE ORD
left outer join 
       (SELECT customer,business,MAX(MARGIN) MARGIN 
        FROM ORDER_TABLE 
        group by customer,business) m
on(ORD.customer = m.customer and ORD.business = m.business)
```